# As a software developer, how to setup a contract with your employer so that you retain ownership of the system you create?

Tags: contracts, hong-kong

I have an employer that's looking to automate their financial system for account receivable, but they're seriously low-balling the salary.

One idea I've been thinking of is to create an employment contract where we both own the IP of the system that I will be creating, and at the point where my employment is terminated, my employer will own the latest version while I also am able to continue developing it on my own and do whatever I want with it.

I know I'll need to consult a local IP lawyer for sure, but I have no idea what this type of work arrangement is called, so I would like some advice on whether this is even a good idea, how to go about doing basic research, and what are the key points I would need to cover in this contract with my potential employer.

EDIT: Location is Hong Kong. Employer has European vendors, and sources highly specialized machine parts. Over 2000 vendors' invoices are manually processed by a team of accountants.

Comment: Where are you located? The US? The UK? Are you an employee? or a contractor?

Comment: If the company is paying you to produce bespoke software, and bearing all the development risk, they won't necessarily want you to sell the same completed product to their competitors.

Answer (score 8):

Realistically, this isn't how business works.

You are either an employee and paid a salary, or a supplier and paid for deliverables. If you actually think there's a business model here for this software, you should set up a company to develop it.

Trying to set up the kind of "hybrid" model you're proposing is something which I can't see either your employer *or any potential future customers* touching with a bargepole because of the legal uncertainties involved.

Answer (score 6):

If you do this, you'll need to do this as a contractor, **not** an employee.

Here is a [sample contract](https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/contract-killer) that web developer freelance consultants use in the UK. I believe it contains the wording about Intellectual Property you're looking for:

> ...
>
> When you've paid us in full--and if this contract hasn't been
> terminated--we'll assign intellectual property rights to you as
> follows:
>
> You'll own the graphic files we produce during your project. We'll
> give you permission to use these files for any purpose.
>
> We'll own the unique combination of elements which constitute the
> complete design. **We'll license it to you, exclusively and in
> perpetuity, for this project only.**
>
> ...

The emphasis in **bold** is mine.

Perhaps, it can be tailored to your specific field and used as a draft before you go see your own lawyer in Hong Kong. Only a Hong Kong lawyer will be able to validate whether this kind of thing will work or not in that jurisdiction. And since you're not really a web developer, only an actual local lawyer can tailor this contract to your actual field.

Writing accounts receivable software is serious business. A bug in such a system could easily cost a client company millions. In addition to a bulletproof disclaimer, you may need to acquire malpractice insurance/legal insurance, and build that extra cost into your contract as well.

Also, it's risky to work for a client who low balls you. A low balling client is the kind of client who may never be satisfied and who may never pay you on time. And sometimes, it's just better to walk away from such clients.

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard of this type of arrangement.

Generally you either:

1: write the software yourself and then sell the licenses to the company.

2: engage as a contractor, whereby you retain ownership of the IP and lease it back to them in perpetuity.

3: you are employed by the company (with all the benefits and protections that come with being an employee over a contractor or entrepreneur) and the company owns the output of your work that they pay you for.

If they are low-balling you, you can try to negotiate a higher salary by making a case for the added value that you could bring, otherwise- look elsewhere for a more appropriate salary package.

Answer (score 1):

If they are “seriously lowballing” your salary: I have a salary range. If you make an offer close to the high end of that range, I’ll sign right now. If you go lower, I will look if I can find a better offer and come back if there is nothing better. If you don’t want to pay the low end of my range, you’ll have to find someone else. I’ll give you an honest assessment of your chances of finding someone that cheap who can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

As either a contractor or an employee, the company is almost certainly going to require that you assign all rights to the software you create to THEM.

This is how things work, you trade your work for their pay.

If you want to develop some software application and maintain ownership for yourself and potentially license it to paying customers, then you can certainly do that but the process is different.

You, as an independent business person, develop this application, documentation, training, support center, etc.  And then YOU (or your representative) try to "sell" it to this and other companies under a license or service agreement.

In this case it's YOUR software and your (or your investor's) company.  They license it and pay you for using it.

Nearly all software applications on the market come into being this way.  Someone identifies an opportunity based on a problem they are familiar with and they come up with a solution that other companies are willing to pay for.  If your idea and software are good, the chances of success are pretty good.  If your idea and/or software are bad, the chances of failure are pretty good.